# ajax and jquery for browser stop url

Tags: html, url, jquery

I just have a question about how to use ajax or jquery to control stop(esc) in browser url section. This is because some data is very large so it will take very long time to wait. If user does not want to wait he can click stop(esc) in url(it was "refresh" before). The user click stop button "X" then html page will do some event. Could you tell me how to manipulate? Does it has API that I can use directly? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var code = (e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.which);
 if(code == 13) { //Enter keycode
   //Do something
 }
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Eric, Thank you for your help. I just wondering can we control it when user click the stop button in URL?